# Endpoints Resolution Error - OAuth v2 Azure - msal-node

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to retrieve an OAuth v2 Token from Microsoft Azure to allow my API to access an SMTP Server (trying to implement Option 1 from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365)). I am attempting to use the `msal-node` library.

I've registered my API and have a token endpoint in the format:

`const tokenEndpoint = https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantID}}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

I have the following code:

```
const msalConfig: Configuration = {
  auth: {
    authority: tokenEndpoint,
    clientId: clientId,
    clientSecret: clientSecret, // Using Client Secret Value
  }
};

const tokenScopes = ['https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send'];

export const getAuth = async () => {
  const cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);
  try {
    const authResponse: AuthenticationResult = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential({
      scopes: tokenScopes
    });
    console.log(`Auth Response: ${authResponse.accessToken}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error (getAuth): ${err}`);
  }
};
```

Upon running `getAuth`, I receive the following error:

```
Error (getAuth): ClientAuthError: endpoints_resolution_error: Error: could not resolve endpoints. Please check network and try again. 
Detail: ClientAuthError: openid_config_error: Could not retrieve endpoints. Check your authority and verify the .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint returns the required endpoints. Attempted to retrieve endpoints from: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{id}}/oauth2/v2.0/token/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

I've doubled checked my endpoints a number of times - what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the documentation [`here`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-node/docs/initialize-confidential-client-application.md), the authority endpoint should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantID}}/`.

Comment: Thanks - I had seen other documentation indicating that I should use one of the other endpoints.